# How do I invoke wait() method in main method? if I use it then it will give java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException

Tags: java

I get an error :

```
    package main_test;
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        Main m = new Main();
        System.out.println("Main Started");
            m.wait();
        System.out.println("Main Terminated");  
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to obtain the monitor lock of the object before you can call `wait` or `notify`, see [Synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sync.html) for more details

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you know what `wait()` does?

Comment: `IllegalMonitorStateException` throws  if the current thread is not  the owner of the object's monitor.

Comment: What do you expect to happen ? Are you using wait to synchronize 2 or more threads or do you want to pause the execution for a given period of time ? (If it is the later, take a look at `Thread.sleep(...)`).

Answer (score 2):

You have to acquire the lock first, before you can call wait. Try something like this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    Main m = new Main();
    System.out.println("Main Started");
    synchronized (m) {
      m.wait();
    }
    System.out.println("Main Terminated");
  }
```

But now the program will not terminate - obviously. Some other thread needs to call `notify()` on the object you called `wait()`. (This is why its a bad idea to use a local variable but this is just an example so...)

See the [java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Main m = new Main();
        System.out.println("Main Started");
        synchronized (m) {
            m.wait();
        }

        System.out.println("Main Terminated");
    }
```

Program wont terminate!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to explicitly acquire monitor by making particular block or method synchronized. wait() releases lock held by executing thread and notify() informs other thread for execution.

Example:

```
Object lock= new Object();
synchronized(lock){
// write your code here. You may use wait() or notify() as per your requirement.
    wait(1000);
    notify();
}
```

Alternatively you may use synchronized method:

```
public synchronized void putMessage(){
// write your code
wait(1000);
notify();
// write your code
}
```